# ¿Cómo deshabilitar años con bootstrap-datetimepicker?

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

¿Cómo puedo deshabilitar los años anteriores a 2016 en mi datetimepicker? Uso la librería bootstrap-datetimepicker, pero en la documentación no he encontrado nada referente a eso, solo encontré agregar la propiedad `startDate:"2016"` pero no me reconoce esa función, mi js es:

```html
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker('setStartDate', '2016')            

        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
                viewMode: 'years',
                format: 'YYYY'
                
            });
        });
      });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba con `minDate`:

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker(
        minDate: '1/1/2016'
        ...
    );
});
```

Comment: Si funciono amigo gracias!